# Visual Studio variable value and type at run time

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Quick question; How can I view variable types and values at run time without modifying the code, but using Visual Studio?

Something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the debugger. You can add break points by clicking on the left side of the IDE.

Then the code will stop executing at that point and you can view the variables before stepping through.

[image]